# How to connect (route) Angular with Slim Framework API?

Tags: php, angularjs, api, slim

I cannot populate the JSON data in the controller from the service.

I am a bit stuck as to how to actually connect them. The service works fine when called by generating the JSON. The controller works as well when I used a repository. I omitted some code in order to save space.

The problem probably lies in the controller, I just don't know what. I would really appreciate some enlightenment.

**Angular Controller** (root/app/user.controller.js)

```
(function() {

    angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('UserController', UserController);

    function UserController($http) {
        var that = this;

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/users'
        }).success(function(data) {
            that.users = data; 
        });
    }   
})();
```

**PHP Service** (root/api/index.php)

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App; 

$app->get('/users', 'getUsers');

$app->run();

function getUsers() {
    $sql = "select * FROM users ORDER BY id";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $wines = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($wines);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}    
?>
```

**JSON Result** from the **PHP Sevice** by visiting http://localhost/root/api/users

```
[{"id":"1","username":"lucentx","first_name":"Aron","last_name":"Barbosa","address":"Manila, Philippines"},{"id":"2","username":"ozzy","first_name":"Ozzy","last_name":"Osbourne","address":"England"},{"id":"3","username":"tony","first_name":"Tony","last_name":"Iommi","address":"England"}]
```

**HTML View** (index.html)

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-controller="UserController as userCtrl">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in userCtrl.users">
            <p>{{user.id}} - {{user.username}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really clear what your problem is

Comment: @charlietfl I cannot populate the data in the controller from the service.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what status is, what is returned etc. I think you have path problem in url since you have a leading `/`. Good excuse to add `$http` error handling also

Comment: @charlietfl F*ck that was it. The leading /. Care to submit it as an answer so I can approve it? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you don't need to place "localhost" in between "url" and "/api/users" ?

Comment: @PekosoGarcia That doesn't work. The solution was to remove the `/` in front of `api/users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the leading `/` in url as that will tell browser to start at root of site ... not in the directory you want it to